# Add offset time with seconds in Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have a streaming data as shown below.

```
"TriggeredDateTime": {"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":5,"day":16},"time":{"hour":4,"minute":56,"second":19,"nano":480389000}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}}
```

I have written SAQL to separate the date and time as below

```
WITH SIGNAL AS (
  SELECT
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.date.year AS yr,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.date.month AS mnth,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.date.day AS date,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.time.hour AS hr,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.time.minute AS mnt,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.time.second AS sec,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.time.nano AS nano,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.offset.totalSeconds AS offset
FROM [input]
)

SELECT 
  CONCAT (yr,'-',mnth,'-',date,'  ',hr,':',mnt,':',sec,':',nano)  AS TriggeredDateTime
INTO
[output]
FROM SIGNAL
```

I have to add the offset seconds also with this time, how to add offset time so that the output second is added with offset time.

Comment: have you tried DateAdd()? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/dateadd-azure-stream-analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/data-types-azure-stream-analytics) and [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/dateadd-azure-stream-analytics):

```
DATEADD(
   second,
   SIGNAL.offset,
   CAST(<your date string> as datetime) 
AS TriggeredDateTime
```

---

Update Answer:

The solution is still based on the usage of [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/data-types-azure-stream-analytics) and [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/dateadd-azure-stream-analytics),but please modify slightly for your sql.

According to my several tests,i found the CAST and DATEADD can't parse `nano` unit,please see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/dateadd-azure-stream-analytics):

[image]

So my idea is convert `nano` into `microsecond`,then please follow below sql:

```
WITH i AS (
  SELECT
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.date.year AS yr,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.date.month AS mnth,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.date.day AS date,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.time.hour AS hr,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.time.minute AS mnt,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.time.second AS sec,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.time.nano/1000 AS nano,
        input.TriggeredDateTime.dateTime.offset.totalSeconds AS offset
FROM input
)
select 
DATEADD(second,offset,
    DATEADD(microsecond,nano,
        CAST(CONCAT (i.yr,'-',i.mnth,'-',i.date,' ',i.hr,':',i.mnt,':',i.sec) as datetime)
    )
)  AS TriggeredDateTime
from i
```

My output with you sample data:

[image]

Comment: I am getting below error when I add DATEADD
```An unexpected error has occured and we have been notified. Please try again in a few minutes.```

Comment: I use below query
```--DATEADD(second,i.offset,CAST(CONCAT (i.yr,'-',i.mnth,'-',i.date,'  ',i.hr,':',i.mnt,':',i.sec,':',i.nano) as datetime)) AS TriggeredDateTime```

Comment: my time data is in format of DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS:nanoSecnds format

Comment: @Antony Please see my above update answer,it works for me.

Comment: This is working fine without nano/micro seconds. If we try to add nano/micro seconds in time format as ```CAST(CONCAT (i.yr,'-',i.mnth,'-',i.date,' ',i.hr,':',i.mnt,':',i.sec,':',i.nano) as datetime)``` it will not work.
But as of now I am ignoring nanoseconds and casting as ```CAST(CONCAT (i.yr,'-',i.mnth,'-',i.date,' ',i.hr,':',i.mnt,':',i.sec) as datetime)``` and it is working fine.  Thanks @Jay Gong

Comment: @Antony You're welcome,Antony. Now, i tried to solve your another issue.